# How to force update of shared calendar (in OS X Yosemite)?

Tags: calendar, ical

I shared a calendar as a public calendar in the Apple Calendar app:

[image]

How can I update the shared calendar when I add or modify entries? I assume this should happen automatically, but even after 1 hour nothing happend. How can I force an update?